# Including hyperlink in an If statement returns true causing all cells that return false to link to a 404 not found webpage

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a fairly convoluted formula but for the problem at hand, it really only concerns the 2nd If statement.

```
=IF(OR($H24="",I$18=""),"",IF(I$18="Additional Notes",IF(ISERROR(MATCH($H24,AdditionalNotes!$H$16:$H445,0)),"",
HYPERLINK("#AdditionalNotes!I"&MATCH($H24,AdditionalNotes!$H:$H,0),"Additional Notes")),


IF(INDEX(MasterSheet!$B$4:$AG$500,MATCH($H24,MasterSheet!$D$4:$D$500,0),
MATCH(I$18,MasterSheet!$B$4:$CF$4,0))=0,"",INDEX(MasterSheet!$B$4:$AG$500,
MATCH($H24,MasterSheet!$D$4:$D$500,0),
MATCH(I$18,MasterSheet!$B$4:$CF$4,0)))))
```

Basically, if a column contains "Additional notes", it'll search a sheet called AdditionalNotes for a name. If that name exists, then I use a `match` function to find the location and include a hyperlink.

I got it to work correctly, except I've know spent about an hour trying to figure out why every other cell that has a value has turned into a link. It'll open up a page in my browser trying to find something in my sharepoint and will just say 404 not found.

Even if i just change the formula to this just be a basic hyperlink, the problem persists

```
=IF(OR($H21="",J$18=""),"",IF(J$18="Additional Notes",HYPERLINK(H3,"Additional Notes")
```

anyone have any idea why this would be happening? any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

*Also -If someone has an idea on how to correctly insert the formula so it doesnt need a scroll other than just pressing enter and putting each line as a separate code block, please share. I know that's annoying so apolgies*

Comment: Good Day,    Does the link value you are trying to pull have http:// in front of it. If not updating your formula to HYPERLINK("http://"&H3, might help

Comment: No, the link isn't even to a website. It's to another cell in a different worksheet.

Comment: Try adding "#"& before H3 then & a cell reference afterwards.  I use this in an automated table contents. A26 is the cell with the worksheet name and A1 is the cell I'm going to on that sheet =HYPERLINK("#"&A26&"!A1",(

Comment: @BradR interesting - what does that do? I'll try this when I get to my desk and revert

Comment: How did that work for you? I set that file up so long ago I'm not sure where the # came from, but I know if i remove it I get a "Can't open specified file error" as much as it is the same file. Now that I've typed that I believe the # tells Excel to look in this workbook for the following worksheet

Comment: Didnt do the trick unfort. I think i've realized the issue isn't within my formula but might be broader concerning hyperlinks in a conditional statement b/c if i just remove all that and try and just include if(B3 = "x","",(hyperlink($A$1,"Addititional Notes"), it still turns any cell that equals x into a hyperlink. (i've opened a new thread as a result)